# How to change the country/region in developer.apple program?

Tags: itunes, ios-appstore, developer-program, billing

Today, I was enrolling my `developer.apple` ID for 1 year, by 99 USD. The region of my ID is currently set as US. That's why it's showing billing information as a format of US.

But I want to purchase the program using a master card from Australia. So that in the billing information section I could select sate/city of Australia from the drop down box. I can change the region in iPhone, iTunes, App Store, but it is not have any impact of by `developer.apple` billing/contact section. What should I do? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I also have the same problem and trying to figure it out since yesterday. It feels like Apple doesn't care about the new developers at all. I sent like 3 emails but I got no response at all from them. I tried enrolling through another ID but didn't work. It always says "Your enrollment in the Apple Developer Program could not be completed at this time.". At this point I don't know what to do. :(